# Eclipse bracket highlighting prefer inner bracket

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting, brackets

Is there a setting in the Eclipse Java editor to change the bracket highlighting to prefer the inner instead of the outer bracket, like in Notepad++? It's pretty confusing to me when I place my cursor on a bracket and it highlights the opposing bracket of a different one instead.

Basically it currently does this: `(`|`(text)text`**`)`**
And I want it to do this: `(`|`(text`**`)`**`text)`

And the other way around:
It does this: **`(`**`text(text)`|`)`
It should do this: `(text`**`(`**`text)`|`)`

Comment: For Java? Not built-in, but maybe (I haven't tried it yet) via the [_Bracketeer_ plug-in](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/bracketeer-java-jdt).

Comment: Yep, seems to do both and even in different colors. That's perfectly acceptable. Can you post it as an answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Eclipse Java editor there is **no such option built in**.

But you can use the [***Bracketeer* plug-in**](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/bracketeer-java-jdt) for that.